# How to password authenticate only one user in windows 7 Share?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-authentication

I have a shared folder on a box running windows 7, I've shared what I want to and disabled password protected sharing. (This is for an office, so ideally I don't want everyone to have to login to access the shared content).

Now what I want is that for that content to be read-only for everyone viewing it (not too bad, set "Everyone" to read only), but I want to be able from my machine authenticate as a user who can make changes and add in files. (I can remote in, but that's not really a convenient solution)

I had this set up once before, but we moved some files around and such and the permissions got messed up and I can't seem to figure out how I did it before.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, there are two sets of permissions to deal with.  File and Folder permissions, as well as the Windows share permissions.  The permissions that are the most restrictive will take priority.  For example giving everyone full permissions at the file level and read-only on the share, will result in  read-only.  The same goes if it was reversed.  Now if you give yourself (your user) read/write on both sets of permissions, you will be good to go.  So "everyone" gets read, while you get read/write.

Comment: Yeah I can add everyone for read. And that lets everyone access it, I guess my main issues is without the password protected sharing going on, I'm unsure how to authenticate myself differently from everyone else. (As there is no log-in). 
I've tried setting a connection up in using `net use` in in the cmd. And I've tried mounting the share using different credentials, but when I got to browse to the folders it still treats me under the _everyone_ group.

Comment: have you give yourself r/w in both file and share permissions?

Comment: The issue I'm having with that is that I don't have a user account that I can give the permissions to. (At least not one that it will let me access from a separate computer without remote desktoping in) 

I'm accessing it from a different computer without the password protected sharing, with that set to disabled it treats me as part of the 'everyone' group. Do you know a way to set it so that when you browse through the Windows Explorer it uses a set account when accessing a network share? (E.g. `\\Shared-pc\sharing\folder`)

Comment: create another share for your user

Answer (score -1):

Fast answer : You can create new user group and set permissions for it adding the user that you need to have write access to it.
You have share and NTFS permissions so you can use both to restrict access in the way you like. In your case try to use [Advanced sharing] -> [Permissions] and add your user with needed priv. or use cacls /G  from elevated prompt = c:\cacls /G .\MyShare myuser:w